# Calling self from RxTableViewSectionedReloadDataSource not working

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I am pretty new to RxSwift and trying to understand how the tableview datasource works.

I have a cell that has two buttons in it. Here is the code of the datasource I made. I am unable to access self. The two buttons should present new view controller when tapped.

```
 let dataSource = RxTableViewSectionedReloadDataSource<SectionModel<String, CustomObject>>(
    configureCell: { (_, table, indexPath, element) in
        guard let cell: AppHelpTableViewCell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: AppHelpTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier,
                                                                         for: indexPath) as? AppHelpTableViewCell
        else { return UITableViewCell() }
        cell.configure(object: element)
        
        cell.introductionBtn.rx.tap.asDriver().drive(onNext: { [weak self] vc in
           self.openIntroductionHelp(object: element)
        }).disposed(by: cell.bag)
        
        cell.onlineBtn.rx.tap.asDriver().drive(onNext: { [weak self] vc in
            self.openIntroductionHelp(object: element)
        }).disposed(by: cell.bag)
        
        return cell
    }
)
```

When I call function from the UIViewController I get this error `Value of type '((AppHelpDetailViewController) -> () -> AppHelpDetailViewController)?' has no member 'openIntroductionHelp'` I am basically trying to call two functions implemented in the view controller that this tableview lives in and I cannot do it from this closures.

I considered using `didSelectRow` but I have two buttons in once cell.

The rx examples I have seen did not have any buttons in them or did not show ho to access self in the `configureCell`. Thanks for any  tips.

Comment: It's `.drive(onNext: { value in }`, you are missing the parameter of the closure. Then, if possible, you can add the `weak self`: `.drive(onNext: { [weak self] aViewController in }

Comment: @Larme Thanks, I have updated my code with new error but I still cannot call anything from the UIViewController. Is there something I am missing here or you are not supposed to call self from this closures?

Comment: Is your dataSource getting defined as a property of the class or is it inside a function?

Comment: @DanielT. its as a property

Comment: @beowulf Then check out my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is not coming from the code you posted, or you didn't post enough code... This compiles just fine:

```
class Example {
    func example() {
        let dataSource = RxTableViewSectionedReloadDataSource<SectionModel<String, CustomObject>>(
            configureCell: { (_, table, indexPath, element) in
                guard let cell: AppHelpTableViewCell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: AppHelpTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier,
                                                                                 for: indexPath) as? AppHelpTableViewCell
                else { return UITableViewCell() }
                cell.configure(object: element)

                cell.introductionBtn.rx.tap.asDriver().drive(onNext: { [weak self] vc in
                    self?.openIntroductionHelp(object: element)
                }).disposed(by: cell.bag)

                cell.onlineBtn.rx.tap.asDriver().drive(onNext: { [weak self] vc in
                    self?.openIntroductionHelp(object: element)
                }).disposed(by: cell.bag)

                return cell
            }
        )
    }

    func openIntroductionHelp(object: CustomObject) { }
}
```

If you want it to be a property of the class, then just make it lazy:

```
class Example {
    lazy var dataSource = RxTableViewSectionedReloadDataSource<SectionModel<String, CustomObject>>(
        configureCell: { (_, table, indexPath, element) in
            guard let cell: AppHelpTableViewCell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: AppHelpTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier,
                                                                             for: indexPath) as? AppHelpTableViewCell
            else { return UITableViewCell() }
            cell.configure(object: element)

            cell.introductionBtn.rx.tap.asDriver().drive(onNext: { [weak self] vc in
                self?.openIntroductionHelp(object: element)
            }).disposed(by: cell.bag)

            cell.onlineBtn.rx.tap.asDriver().drive(onNext: { [weak self] vc in
                self?.openIntroductionHelp(object: element)
            }).disposed(by: cell.bag)

            return cell
        }
    )

    func openIntroductionHelp(object: CustomObject) { }
}
```

Comment: the lazy var did it. Thanks a lot for help